# Can i use Box2D-objects side by side with Cocos2d-X objects?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, box2d

Cocos2d-x supports the physics engines [Box2D and Chipmunk](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Physics_Engine) and i used it until now via Cocos2d-x objects like cocos2d::PhysicsWorld or cocos2d::PhysicsJoint (we're talking C++ here). Now i want to integrate some custom Joint that is available for Box2D. Also, i experience problems with tunneling at high speed that i hope to get rid of by implementing some objects directly with Box2D (b2World etc.).

**Is it possible to define some Box2D objects and just add them to the Cocos2d-X physics?** And if it's not, do i have to reimplement the whole physics stuff from world-start to fixture-end?
The official [Box2D tutorial](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Box2D) doesn't mention the native objects at all and seems be a little outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems no one is willing to answer this. 
As i progressed i can give others looking for an answer the hint, that i think you have to adapt completely to Box2D, create a b2world, add b2bodies etc. 
For me it wasn't complicated and the simulation is much more accurate. It solved the problems i was facing with the cocos2dx-objects, so if you run into problems like tunneling or want to use more sophisticated features of Box2D, i'd suggest switching.